# Switching Environments in PHP

Tags: php, sql, database, windows, phpstorm

I am having trouble understanding the dynamic structure of PHP. I don't know PHP very well but I do know how to code JavaScript, HTML, and CSS.

A website that I help manage has an environment meant for Macs. I am not a Mac user in the least and would know how to get this local instance of the website up and running.

Tried using Vagrant, got it and not many tutorials tell me how it could be done, so then I used PhpStorm to run the server then I keep getting this error on line 21 of this file.

I am trying to find where I point the system directory and find the `autoload.php` file which I do have. But being originally created on a Mac makes it very difficult.

Here is the error:

```
Warning: require(D:\Vagrant 
project\compasshb.com\public/boostrap/autoload.php): failed to open stream: 
No such file or directory in D:\Vagrant 
project\compasshb.com\public\index.php on line 22

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'D:\Vagrant 
project\compasshb.com\public/boostrap/autoload.php' 
(include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in D:\Vagrant 
project\compasshb.com\public\index.php on line 22
```

Makes no sense to me.
Here is line 22 in index.php:

```
<?php

/**
 * Laravel - A PHP Framework For Web Artisans.
 *
 * @author   Taylor Otwell <taylorotwell@gmail.com>
 */

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register The Auto Loader
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Composer provides a convenient, automatically generated class loader for
| our application. We just need to utilize it! We'll simply require it
| into the script here so that we don't have to worry about manual
| loading any of our classes later on. It feels nice to relax.
|

*/

require __DIR__.'/boostrap/autoload.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Turn On The Lights
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| We need to illuminate PHP development, so let us turn on the lights.
| This bootstraps the framework and gets it ready for use, then it
| will load up this application so that we can run it and send
| the responses back to the browser and delight our users.
|
*/

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Run The Application
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Once we have the application, we can handle the incoming request
| through the kernel, and send the associated response back to
| the client's browser allowing them to enjoy the creative
| and wonderful application we have prepared for them.
|
*/

$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);

$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);

   $response->send();

   $kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

Comment: Are you using Vagrant to run Windows inside a Mac?

Comment: If it's a Laravel app I suggest you try to use Laravels own environment, Laravel Homestead. They have decent documentation on how to get going. https://laravel.com/docs/master/homestead

Comment: A very simple vagrant box is https://box.scotch.io/ - it's very easy to install and use. Of course you first need to install https://www.vagrantup.com/ and perhaps https://www.virtualbox.org/ - The above seems to be an laravel installation, here is a guide you can use to get up running: https://laravel.com/docs/5.0#install-laravel

Comment: You can find the website I am trying to get a local instance of is right here on GitHub, https://github.com/CompassHB/compasshb.com?files=1. Box.scotch.io pretty cool but the error is straight from php storm which has its own server based ssh. So no need for vagrant. Just trying to find direactory of the php so I can tweak it with windows.

Comment: I am not trying to run windows inside a Mac. Sorry for not clerifying. I know the dev, and he does everything on a Mac.